# Pandas: what is a simple way to group by two columns and build a new flat dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame `df1` with columns A,B,C,D. I want to group by A,B and then have a new
data frame `df2` with columns set to size of df1["B"] for each df["A"] and index rows set to df1["A"].

Here's a code I currently have to solve this, but I wonder if there's a simple way:

```
grouped = data.groupby(["A", "B"]) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(grouped.size()) 
cols = df.ix["B"].T.columns

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

idxr = [ d[0] for d in df.index ]

for d in set(idxr):
    row = df.ix[d].T 
    df2 = df2.append(row)

df2.index = set(idxr)
```

Example

**Input**

**A | B | C | D |**
a1  b1  c1  d1
a2  b2  c1  d2
a2  b1  c1  d3
a3  b2  c2  d4

**Output**
b1 | b2
  1  0
  1  1
  0  1

Comment: Can you show an example of the result you want?  It's hard to use your code without sample data.

Comment: Updated post with the example. Couldn't make tables look neat with markdown :/ But the output table is 3x2 and index rows are: a1, a2, a3

Comment: Do you want the values in each cell to indicate the number of times that combination of A and B values occurs in the original DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a much cleaner way of doing it...

```
output = data.groupby(["A", "B"]).size()#dont have to call the constructor again
output = output.unstack('B').fillna(0)
```

**output**

```
B   b1  b2
A
a1   1   0
a2   1   1
a3   0   1
```